# Is it actually possible to insert the shortcut "C-M-\" in a German keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Goal: I want to use the function `indent-region` with the default shortcut <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>.

Problem: I use a German keyboard layout. To insert "\" I have to type either <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>ß</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>ß</kbd>, because the "ß" is overloaded with "?" and "\" (see: [QWERTZ layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Germany.svg) in the upper right corner).

Question: Is it possible to to input the shortcut <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> without tweaking emacs or the OS on a German keyboard?

If it is not I would just change the shortcut to something easily accessible. The main reason I want this to work is that it works out of the box on a default emacs installation.

Comment: That depends on the operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've experienced this problem and found the following info helpful from the ["Alt Gr Key" page on emacswiki.org](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AltGrKey):-

> Emacs keys may seem to be “hidden” (perhaps only) on MS Windows because **AltGr + LeftControl + key** is just **AltGr + key**.
>
> Solution 1: Using the Right Control
>
> But you can type those keys even on MS Windows! The trick is that you must type **AltGr** as the first key, and **Ctrl** must be the **right** control key, not the left one.

After experimenting on a German keyboard, I can execute `C-M-\` like: `AltGr+RCtrl+M+\`, where `RCtrl` is my right-Ctrl key, `M` is my left/only Alt key and `\` is my ß?\ key. (The value of `w32-alt-is-meta` is `t`.)

This key-chord is cumbersome so perhaps it's better to define the `C-M-ß` combination as suggested by @OlegPavliv.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your .emacs

```
(define-key (current-global-map) (kbd "C-M-ß") 'indent-region)
```

This way it will indent the region on C-M-ß

Answer (score 1):

Press `C-M`.

Release.

Press `AltGr-ß` to produce \

Works for me. Where is the problem?

Comment: This results in the output "\". It is as if I just press AltGr + "ß".

Comment: In Emacs, C-M-\ means control-meta-backslash, not control-M, backslash. If ctrl-esc generates control-meta for you, this is a good solution.